# Multi-level linking of libraries causes missing functionality

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries

I'm at an interesting predicament. I have static library A, which contains logging functionality that all our executables will need. Static library A is linked by Shared object B because. Some of our executables link only to shared object B. The problem is that they cannot use our public logging functions that B inherits from static object A. I'm getting linker errors that functionality is not found. I'm assuming that shared object B makes things inaccessible in static library A.

```
For simplicity:
libA.a [logging.h] <- libB.so <- executable [wants to use logging.h]
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Because obviously those symbols (from `A`) which you would like to use in executable are not exported from `B`. So, you'd rather have to transform `A` to shared library as well and export all necessary symbols (public API) which you would like to use. Then you can link it against both `B` and executable. This way you would also still preserve memory usage efficiency, as there will be no code duplication.

Comment: Why don't you link in your executable libA.a?

Comment: @mistapink: Possible, but not the best idea because this results in code duplication, i.e. the same code would be linked in both `B` and executable. This is one of the main reasons why shared libraries are preferred over the static ones for deployment.